# Таблица и столбец пола

Tags: sql, postgresql

У меня есть таблица `People`

```
CREATE TABLE People (id serial, name varchar(20), surname varchar(20), age int, gender varchar(1));
```

Как мне сделать, чтобы в столбец gender можно было вводить только либо M либо F и ничего больше. Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так:

```sql
CREATE TABLE people (
  id serial
, name VARCHAR(20)
, surname VARCHAR(20)
, age INT
, gender VARCHAR(1) CHECK (gender IN ('F', 'M'))
);
```